# Using go.dbus with omxplayer on Raspberry Pi

Tags: go, raspberry-pi, dbus, omxplayer

I am trying to using the D-Bus interface on omxplayer in order to control the running video.  I'm attempting this using the go.dbus library found here:  https://github.com/guelfey/go.dbus

The omxplayer documentation provides a dbuscontrol.sh script that I can use successfully.  It sets some environments variable and then can use dbus-send in order to query omxplayer.

I'm trying to reproduce this in Go but I keep getting the error "The name org.mpris.MediaPlayer2 was not provided by any .service files"

Here is my code:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "os"

    "github.com/guelfey/go.dbus"
    "github.com/guelfey/go.dbus/introspect"
)

func main() {
    os.Setenv("OMXPLAYER_DBUS_ADDR", "/tmp/omxplayerdbus.pi")
    os.Setenv("OMXPLAYER_DBUS_PID", "/tmp/omxplayerdbus.pi.pid")
    conn, err := dbus.SessionBus()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    node, err := introspect.Call(conn.Object("org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.omxplayer", "/org/mpris/MediaPlayer2"))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    data, _ := json.MarshalIndent(node, "", "    ")

    var s []string
    err = conn.BusObject().Call("org.freedesktop.DBus.ListNames", 0).Store(&s)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "Failed to get list of owned names:", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    fmt.Println("Currently owned names on the session bus:")
    for _, v := range s {
        fmt.Println(v)
    }

    os.Stdout.Write(data)
}
```

Comment: you have to use the content of the files - the address looks something like unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-mQJTjffxVL,guid=cb5b9d6eb7d17e381a9ce1c2590d99aa but I'm still not able to call any dbus function for omxplayer

Answer (score 0):

OMXplayer does not use the system or session bus, but instead uses its own bus, the path to this bus is the content of the file pointed to by the  `OMXPLAYER_DBUS_ADDR` environment variable.

You can see that the dbuscontrol.sh script sets that up on [lines 5-8](https://github.com/popcornmix/omxplayer/blob/master/dbuscontrol.sh#L5) (specifically line 7).

In your case, you'll need to open that file, read its contents, and use that in a call to [`dbus.Conn.Dial()`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/guelfey/go.dbus?tab=doc#Dial).

Something similar to this may work:

```golang
import (
    "log"
    "io/ioutil"
    "github.com/guelfey/go.dbus"
)

func getOMXPlayerDBUSAddr() string {
    content, err := ioutil.ReadFile("/tmp/omxplayerdbus.pi")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    return string(content)
}

func main() {
    conn, err := dbus.Dial(getOMXPlayerDBUSAddr())
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // The rest of the code goes here
    node, err := introspect...
}
```